# Install older version of PHP? (5.4.xx)

Tags: php, apt-get

How do I install older version of PHP (5.4.xx - preferably the latest 5.4.45)?

I have tried look on Debian's website (I'm using Debian 8 Jessie) but they do not archive old versions.

Comment: You can compile them from source.

Comment: @svrnm Can you point me in the right direction to start doing that?

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/building-php-5.4-from-source-on-debian-squeeze

Comment: @ADAMPOKE111 StackOverflow is a place for asking questions about development and code issues. You question is more likely to be answered on serverfault. I've flagged it for moderation (so that it could be moved there). Also, if it's not absolutely necessary, try using PHP 5.6+ instead of the 5.4.x. It has great performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

[download from here](http://php.net/get/php-5.4.45.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror)

[Steps to install from tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

[Better instructions on installing](https://serverfault.com/questions/387274/compile-php5-4-for-apache-php5-3-already-apt-get-installed)

or

[Try this from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/353550/how-to-install-old-php-version)